# jQuery .offset() doesn't work properly at all in every browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I defined these variables:

```
var about = 0;
var music = $('.music-main').offset();
var programming = $('.programming-main').offset();
var contact = $('.contact-main').offset();
```

and then try to animate scrolling to specific parts on my page on button click.

```
 case 0: $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0}); break;
 case 1: $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: music.top}); break;
 case 2: $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: programming.top}); break;
 case 3: $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: contact.top}); break;
```

but it scrolls to a different location. It even scrolls to a different position for each element.

Comment: Do you want to create a fiddle for this so we can see it in action? http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to call the offset only after the page has loaded because otherwise the coordinates will not be correct.

So do something like this:

```
$( window ).load(function() {
  var about = 0;
  var music = $('.music-main').offset();
  var programming = $('.programming-main').offset();
  var contact = $('.contact-main').offset();
}
```

It would be even better to calculate the offset at the moment of the click so changes in page size in between the load and the click will not have any effect:

```
var about = 0;
var music = $('.music-main');
var programming = $('.programming-main');
var contact = $('.contact-main');

case 0: $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0}); break;
case 1: $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: music.offset().top}); break;
case 2: $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: programming.offset().top}); break;
case 3: $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: contact.offset().top}); break;
```